# How to center align onDemandGrid headers

Tags: javascript, html, css, dgrid, center-align

I am using dgrid's onDemandGrid and would like to center align specific column headers but not all headers in a grid. How would I go about accomplishing this?

I have the following in my css file:

```
.mywidget h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.mywidget h3, p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.dgrid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    font-size:larger;
}
.dgrid-row-odd {
  background: #F2F5F9;
}
.dgrid-column-A{
  width: 80px;
}
.dgrid-column-B{
  width: 120px;
}
.dgrid-column-C {
  width: 80px;
}
.dgrid-column-D {
  width: 120px;
}
.dgrid-column-E {
  width: 50px;
}
.dgrid-column-F {
  width: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.dgrid-header .dgrid-column-B {
  width: 120px;
  text-align:center;
}
```